# Set ColorMode to print Access Report in VBA

Tags: ms-access, printing, vba

I have a problem setting the printing properties for my access reports with VBA.
I have tried to set the values using

```
Application.Printer.PrintQuality = acPRPQHigh
Application.Printer.PaperSize = acPRPSA5
Application.Printer.ColorMode = acPRCMColor
```

With

```
Debug.Print Application.Printer.Device
```

I tested if the Application.Printer is set to the right printer, which is the case.
Still, the properties are not used when the reports are printed with

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "Report"
```

Answer (score 0):

May I can help you. Each Report has it`s own printer-object, so you should use

```
MyReport.Printer.PrintQuality = acPRPQHigh
MyReport.Printer.PaperSize = acPRPSA5
MyReport.Printer.ColorMode = acPRCMColor
```

or in Report_Activate:

```
Private Sub Report_Activate()
    Set Me.Printer = Application.Printer
End Sub
```